# Почему нет доступа к репозиторию?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, развертывание, bitbucket, capistrano

Настраиваю деплой для проекта и столкнулся с проблемой:
При запуске скрипта

`cap production deploy:check`
вижу ошибку

```
INFO [16ef9c10] Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:test/pereezd-test.git as deployer@ip
DEBUG [16ef9c10] Command: ( export GIT_ASKPASS="/bin/echo" GIT_SSH="/tmp/test/git-ssh.sh" ; /usr/bin/env git ls-remote --heads git@bitbucket.org:test/pereezd-test.git )
DEBUG [16ef9c10]    Permission denied (publickey).
DEBUG [16ef9c10]    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
DEBUG [16ef9c10]    and the repository exists.
```

Но если зайти на сервер по ssh и вручную запустить git clone, все работает отлично. Т.е. с ключами все нормально.

production.rb

```
# server-based syntax
# ======================
# Defines a single server with a list of roles and multiple properties.
# You can define all roles on a single server, or split them:

server 'ip', user: 'deployer', roles: %w{app db web}, primary: true
# server 'example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{app web}, other_property: :other_value
# server 'db.example.com', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{db}

set :ssh_options, {
forward_agent: false }

# role-based syntax
# ==================

# Defines a role with one or multiple servers. The primary server in each
# group is considered to be the first unless any  hosts have the primary
# property set. Specify the username and a domain or IP for the server.
# Don't use `:all`, it's a meta role.

role :app, %w{deployer@ip}
role :web, %w{deployer@ip}
role :db,  %w{deployer@ip}

set :rails_env, :production
```

Ключи подгружаю с помощью keychain

${HOME}/.bashrc:

```
keychain ~/.ssh/bitbucket
. ~/.keychain/`uname -n`-sh
```

Скорее всего дело в нем, но я не понимаю как по-другому исправить следующее поведение:
захожу по ssh на сервер, запускаю ssh agent, добавляю ключ ssh-add, после логаута все по новой, ключ не сохраняется.

команда на сервере ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

```
authenticated via a deploy key.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
test/test:  -- deployer@ip
```

***UPDATE***
Мой алгоритм действий:

на сервере-

```
- генерирую пару ключей

- запускаю ssh agent

- публичный ключ добавляю в битбакет

- приватный ключ добавляю в агент( ssh-add key) с вводом пароля

- пытаюсь клонировать репозиторий на сервере, хост добавляю в known_hosts, репозиторий успешно клонируется
```

локально -

```
- не закрывая ssh сессию( если закрыть, агент тоже выключится) пробую провести деплой, получаю ошибку доступа к репозиторию, проверку типа версии руби проходит корректно.
```

Получается проблемы две:

1) Нужно как то заставить агент не закрываться после логаута или чтобы ключи добавлялись автоматически( это я пытался решить с помощью keychain)

2) Нужно таки получить доступ к репозиторию при деплое.

Comment: Смотреть ответ  + Я просто удалил **Deployment Key**, на данный момент мне он не нужен. И это сработало

Comment: если с локальной машины доступ к репозиторию есть, то, наверно, имеет смысл таки разрешить `forward_agent`.